Conditional Format highest 6 values in a row on google sheets
Im trying to highlight (conditionally format) the top 6 values in a row on google sheets
I've found previous formulas that work only for columns and not rows
=$C2>=large($C$2:$C,6)
For example that would highlight the top 6 values in a column, but when you change it to a row
=$C2>=large($C$2:$W$2,6)
It then highlights all the values and not the top 6?
Does anyone have a fix for this, or not possible?
Thanks


You may try:
=C$2>=large($C$2:$W$2,6)


You're a legend, I see my mistake now. Thanks, if i were to take this one step further and only include the top 6 including duplicates, how would i achieve that? for example if there were 10 results of (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2)
